# How to set n_trials for multiple processes when using parallelization?

Tags: optuna

When I execute code without parallel computation, `n_trials` in the `optimize` function means how many trials the program runs. When executed via parallel computation (following the tutorial [here](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/10_key_features/004_distributed.html) via launching it again in another console), it does `n_trials` for each process, not for all the sum of processes like I would like.

Is there a way to make sure that the sum of all parallel processes' trials are equal to a fixed number, regardless of how many process I launch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [`MaxTrialsCallback`](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.study.MaxTrialsCallback.html#optuna.study.MaxTrialsCallback) is the exact feature for such a situation.